# AngularJS Layout - Extra Options are Buggy?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I used layout-gt-md go give an element a ng-hide if the page resolution is bigger than 1280px. But it doesn't really work.

This is the Complete Code:

```
<div layout-gt-md hide-gt-md id="mobileContentSwitcher" ng-controller="ContentSwitcherCtrl">
    <md-tabs md-stretch-tabs="always" md-selected="selectedIndex">
        <md-tab label="tab1">
            <md-tab-label>
                <md-icon md-svg-icon="content.svg"></md-icon>
            </md-tab-label>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="tab2">
            <md-tab-label>
                <md-icon md-svg-icon="users.svg"></md-icon>
            </md-tab-label>
        </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
</div>
```

hide-gt-md worked fine. But I want to remove the HTML Elements, complete from the DOM.

So what I do wrong? Or is this not possible with this?

I tryed to realize that on the Controller with:

```
$scope.Visibility = function () {
    angular.element(find('#mobileContentSwitcher')).addClass('yourClass');
};
```

of I want to try first to give the element a class, to check that this is working. (i am totally new to JavaScript) but this line code don't do anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: (EDIT)

controller:
What this does is set $scope.highResolution to true or false based on the expression inside this () if the value of resolution is greater than 1280 then highResolution would be true. Otherwise its false.

```
$scope.highResolution = (resolution > 1280) ? true : false;
```

HTML:
In the html ng-hide, ng-show, etc all are looking for true or false you can either pass a variable with the value or do the expression directly in the ng-hide attribute. Any variable used in the attribute like this: ng-hide="resolution > 1280" "resolution" must be assigned to $scope, e.g $scope.resolution = 1380; ...

```
<div ng-hide="highResolution"> Content To Hide </div>
```

To watch the window size and reevaluate the value of $scope.highResolution you would do something like the following.

```
.controller('someController', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) {

    var win = angular.element($window);
    win.bind('resize', function () {
        $scope.resolution = this.outterWidth;
        $scope.highResolution = ($scope.resolution > 1280) ? true : false;
        $scope.$apply(); // you may not need this.
    });
}])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but he still dont add the Class "YourClass"

Comment: @SvenBudak you could use ng-class="{yourClass: someCondition}" in your controller $scope.someCondition should evaluate to true and "yourClass" will be applied to the element.

Comment: Thanks, but i tryed to add the class only, to see that the element choser works. i dont realy need any class on my element... i want to trigger ng-hide="hide()" when the resolution is OVER 1280px and i want to trigger ng-show="show()" when the resolution is UNDER 1280px... my problem is that i try to work first time in my life with JavaScript. Normaly i am a Designer.

Comment: Thanks alot. I tryed it now with ng-if="resolution > 1280" and in Scope: http://prntscr.com/bnnyfu But this dont realy work for me =/

Comment: @SvenBudak In the example link you provided the expression (resolution > 1280) should be ($scope.resolution > 1280) because you assigned the value 1380 to $scope.resolution.

Comment: Thanks alot! This works for me, i just dont realize that it works because he dont change values on resizing the browser window. How i can i make that your code in the controller work with resizing Browser Window Width?

Comment: @SvenBudak you would assign the $scope.resolution = window.outterWidth or whatever measurement you are using to calculate the resolution. When the window changes your $scope.resolution changes Ill edit the answer with more details

Answer (score 0):

```
var w = window.innerWidth;//width of user window
var maxWide = 1280;//the cutoff width
var hideDiv = document.getElementById('mobileContentSwitcher');
function checkAndHide() {
  if(w >= maxWide){//updated to >=
    hideDiv.style.display = 'none';
    //or use ng-hide class 
    hideDiv.classList.add('ng-hide');
  }else hideDiv.style.display = 'block';
  //or else hideDiv.classList.remove('ng-hide')
```

call that on dom ready or resize -

or:

```
$scope.Visibility = function () {
  var x = angular.element('#mobileContentSwitcher');
  x.classList.add('yourClass');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it dont work for me. Is it possible that i have to place the Ctrl 1 lvl upper? http://prntscr.com/bnjcyz and http://prntscr.com/bnjd75 There is no change on the element..

Comment: then your issues go beyond the scope of your question because both of those answers are valid js

Comment: the controller should be on the parent of the elements that your are trying to manipulate - as long as all of the elements your working with are wrapped inside the controller you should be good  http://codepen.io/mcgraw/pen/eef9dde92cecce50179a2ba8958380f4

Comment: yeah with your codesnipped from codepen it works: document.getElementById('mobileContentSwitcher').classList.add('imAClassAddedWit‌​hJs'); Is it possible to select the same element in that is the controller includet? then i dont need to set a ID... At last i want to trigger ng-hide="hide()" when resolution is bigger than 1280px...

Comment: im confused, you already have an id set on layout-gt-md but if you'd rather not use an id you can use querySelector on the attribute(s): 

var el = document.querySelector(['layout-gt-md']);

- that will return the first instance of the element that has an attribute layout-gt-md

Comment: The Div around looks like now that: <div ng-hide="hide()" ng-show="show()" ng-controller="ContentSwitcherCtrl"> layout-gt-md is buggy, so i remove it again.

Comment: never seen ng-hide used in that way - ive only used it as a class name and where did your grid attributes go? without those your layout will be wrong -

Comment: you are right... so stupid from me... i mean i have to trigger ng-if... trigger if width larger than 1280px... i want that the element removed complete from the HTML DOM because i think that its better for performance and for SEO

Comment: Isnt it better when i do it with angular stuff?

Comment: The .ng-hide CSS class is predefined in AngularJS and sets the display style to none (using an !important flag) - that does not remove the element from the DOM - JS native .remove will remove it from the DOM

Comment: I got now $scope.showCS = true; in my Scope... How can i make it to false if resolution is larger than 1280px?

Comment: create a helper function w/in the controller:

`$scope.chkWide() {
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var maxWide = 1280;
    var el = document.getElementById('mobileContentSwitcher');
   
     if(w >= maxWide){
         return true;
     }else return false;
 }`

then in your markup $scope.showCS = $scope.chkWide() -- that will return the boolean to determine a show/hide